# HTML output via an XSL transform involving special characters

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xhtml

I am having trouble transforming particular characters from an XML feed into XHTML.

I am using the following example to demonstrate the problem.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<paragraph>some text including the –, ã and ’ characters</paragraph>
```

Here is the XSLT I am applying:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" 
            encoding="UTF-8" 
            indent="yes"
            doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />
    <xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head></head>
            <body>
        <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
            </body>
        </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the resultant XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <p>some text including the â€“, Ã£ and â€™ characters</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The characters from the original XML are being replaced with new ones.

Firstly I want to check whether there is something wrong with my encoding which causes this issue?

Am I supposed to do something using entities if I want to map the special characters to display correctly in XHTML? If so how do I use these within an XSLT and do I need to know every single possible value that could be in my XML feed in advance?

Comment: The resulting XHTML looks a lot like a UTF-8 file that was opened with an editor that expected ISO-8859-1 or similar 8-bit format (the doubled characters give it away). Take a look at it using a hex dump, and I bet that you'll see that the transform worked as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree the kdgregory: The output file looks to be in UTF-8, but its reader thinks it is in something else (ISO-8859-1 or CP-1252 (the default for Windows)).  Try adding a content type directly in the HTML head element:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: This makes the file render correctly in the browser, thanks. This would also explain why it displayed correctly in some browsers but not others.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound stupid but are you sure the xml file is actually utf-8? It's one thing to put it in the prolog but the file itself could be using another encoding.

Comment: I was using XMLSpy to create the file and I believe that uses UTF-8 as standard. I've even re-created it in Notepad saving specifically as UTF-8 to make sure.

Comment: And the output file? Maybe the xsl tool you are using is at fault here.